# How to use re.sub in pandas datafram

Tags: python, dataframe, python-re

```
def not_value(x):
    if type(x) == str:
        re.sub(r'(\s+)', np.nan, x)
    else:
        pass

df_copy=df.copy()
df_copy.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: not_value(x))
```

I have checked the value in the dataframe is a string. But it always shows that
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, float found. What is the problem with it?

Thank you for giving me an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to replace values in a certain string column with `np.nan`, when the value of the string is all whitespace, you can do the following. You may want to edit the regular expression if it doesn't matter that it is *all* whitespace or not:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': ['s ', '  ']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

spaces = df['col3'].str.contains('^\s+$')
df.loc[spaces, 'col3'] = np.nan
df
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2 col3
0     1     3   s 
1     2     4  NaN
```